# SDL2 graphics will draw in main process but not in separate thread

Tags: sdl2

I'm having an issue that I'm absolutely stuck on and my ability to debug this issue has been exhausted.

I am implementing a base for a 2D game where I am handling my keyboard input, logic, and graphics in their own thread.  The input and logic work flawlessly, and as far as I know, the graphics is working too... except that the graphics is not drawn to the screen.

If I put all of my graphics logic into my main process, it works fine.  For example:

```
TTextObject* text = new TTextObject("My text", 12, TPoint(0,0), {255,0,0});
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_R, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_RenderClear(_R);
text->draw();
SDL_RenderPresent(_R);
```

The TTextObject accepts the actual text, font size, origin point, and color.

As I stated before, this works absolutely fine within the main process of the program.  However, when I split up the code, and take the same exact code and use it in a separate thread, it will not work.

I have debugged to make sure that:

- The Renderer object is the same
- The text object is the same
- The window is the same (it should be at least as the renderer is created with respect to the window).

**My source code is found at: https://Zulukas@bitbucket.org/Zulukas/gamebase.git**

It should compile just fine on Ubuntu; I haven't tested it on Windows or any other Linux distro.  Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I strongly recommend to not separate your game out into threads unless you really understand the implications of multi-threading your game and how it changes your engine architecture. Multi-threading is mostly done out of a need for performance, considering you are using the SDL Renderer, it's unlikely multi-threading your app is where you need to be focusing to make your game better.

Answer (score 2):

SDL isn't built to support multithreaded rendering. It's a miracle that your code doesn't immediately crash. In most graphics APIs rendering has to be done on the thread where the renderer was created.